# Adding an int to an array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm trying to convert an int (4bytes) and add it into an array of chars. I do the converting from int to char using this code I found from stackoverflow.

```
unsigned char buffer[4];
buffer[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
buffer[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
buffer[3] = value & 0xFF;
```

where value is the int value that I want to convert.
It works perfectly fine, for example, if I were to convert the value 100 using the code above, it will give the following: '\0', '\0', '\0', 'd'

And I'm trying to add this into an array of char I have (its added at an index i, not at index 0), but since the 1st character is null, my array of char (cstring) gets cut off from there. So I can only see the strings uptil index i - 1, and since null comes at index i, my cstring ends there. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to overcome this situation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do with your char array?

Comment: "And I'm trying to add this into an array of char" - that seems to be where you are having the problem so it would help to show your code there.

Comment: @Adam, so I'm trying to have this char array to hold some data that I'll be using, so the 1st part of the array is the name, size of the data, and the data itself.

Comment: int could be longer than 1 character,, it's not possible. But if you want to add an int to an array of string. It will be possible

Comment: "that I'll be using". That's nice. Using for what? You're adding a null terminator to a string and wondering why it gets treated like a null terminator. So I ask again, what do you want to happen?

Comment: @MichaelAntonio Yeah, for a byte, the max value I can have is 255, so I'm trying to divide it into a buffer of 4 unsigned chars, so I can represent bigger values.

Comment: @Adam, The value inside buffer[0] is a null terminator, but thats the the end of my data, but since its a null terminator, its terminating my char array, so I dont want my array to be null terminated.

Comment: `& 0xFF` is unnecessary since the high bits will be implicitly truncated anyway

Comment: `&0xFF` is good practice, even though it does not actually affect the generated machine code.  It should prevent compiler warnings about overflow, and indicates the users preference to pull 8 bits out of 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `strcpy` or any `str*` commands if you are moving *binary data*. Use `memcpy` instead.

```
unsigned char buffer[4];
buffer[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
buffer[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
buffer[3] = value & 0xFF;
memcpy(otherstring + offset, buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

or

```
char* buffer = otherstring + offset;
buffer[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
buffer[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
buffer[3] = value & 0xFF;
```

Comment: I dont think this works, since for certain values, (lets say value == 100), the value in buffer[0] is '\0', so my char array is null terminated there,

Comment: It works. The problem is that you are mishandling your char array after you create it. You're hopefully not doing something like `printf(myarray);` You need to treat it as a binary sequence of bytes, not a string of printable characters that is null delimited.

Comment: oh....so even though visibly, my char array has been terminated, the data behind still exists, its just not seen when I hover my mouse over the char array variable, is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: yes. the data is still there. Use a memory debugger to see it.